# What tips would you give to a beginner violinist to execute these pieces well?

Tags: practice, violin, beginner, orchestra

I am practicing these two pieces to enter orchestra, but I am having difficulty practicing it. Specifically, as I am quite a beginner, I am not sure about many things technique wise. For example, how should this sound like, or what could I do to better it? Things like this are always in my head. Here is a link to the orchestral recording for Symphony No. 15 in G Major:

Here is a link to the orchestral recording of Appalachian Festival:

I am aware that my question is quite broad, but really any information or tips for a beginner would greatly help. You may also search for the violin parts (I play violin) of those pieces. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is too broad for a stackexchange question.  This is what a teacher is for.  Failing that, you can try finding mutual feedback groups online and share recordings, but I've found those to give poor quality feedback

Comment: Without a teacher, it's going to be very hard if not impossible to learn even basics that you'll need to qualify for most orchestras.

Comment: The first and most important piece of advice is "get help." Even if you can't find or afford a teacher, can you find an advanced student who's willing to listen and give you tips? Even a non-violinist who can read music well, like a parent, choir teacher, etc., can tell you if you're making basic mistakes in pitches or rhythms. Ideally, ask someone in the orchestra you're auditioning for for help—they *want* good players, and want you to do well. Auditions, especially for school orchestras, are usually graded on a few factors, some of which are more important than others...

Comment: ... You should solve your "biggest problems" first. Ask yourself (and others!): 1) Am I playing the right notes (pitches)? 2) Am I keeping a steady tempo, and playing the notes for the right durations (rhythm)? 3) Am I playing in tune (intonation)? —Only if these things are right should you worry about anything else. If they are, then, 4) Am I getting a good tone (bow control—using a firm bow weight, enough speed, and controlling the contact point, not too close to bridge or fingerboard)? 5) Am I doing the dynamics that are printed? —And then you can worry about finer details like...

Comment: 6) Am I using the right "style" for this piece—is my staccato appropriate for Mozart? (I'm guessing, from this question, that this is a level of detail that you don't need to work on right now) or 7) am I adding musically sensitive and appropriate "expression," beyond even what's marked on the page?